# Pathfinder - Marksman Powers with Thrown Weapon

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

I'm playing a Marksman using a thrown weapon. I'm curious if some of the powers apply. For example, [Prevenom Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/p/prevenom#TOC-Prevenom-Weapon) says the weapon maintains the coating as long as it remains in your grip (ranged weapons bestow effect on ammunition). Technically, a thrown weapon is not in your grip once it's thrown, nor is it ammunition for a weapon, so is this power usable for my weapon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By an absolutely strict parsing of the RAW, no, this power would not work with your thrown weapons. However, this is one of those times when the strict RAW is flatly stupid. Ask your DM about it. This is an obvious situation for house-ruling it to work, and making the case for such should be trivially easy with any even somewhat reasonable DM.

Comment: Thank you very much! My GM is a great guy, I am sure we can work out something.

Answer (score 2):

Since the marksman power extends Prevenom to ranged weapon ammo, only the most unreasonable of DMs would rule that you couldn't apply it to a thrown weapon, even though you could technically interpret the rules that way. It seems pretty clear-cut how it should function.

Looking through the other powers, I have similar thoughts. While many powers explicitly mention bolts, arrows, slings, there's no reason they shouldn't apply to darts and shuriken as well. For example, summoning a shuriken with Bolt is logical and since shurikens do far less damage, is probably not OP. But summoning a dagger might be crossing the line since it can be used as a melee weapon.

I'd say it needs to be decided on a case by case basis with your GM but for the most part your powers should apply.

Comment: Oh, that is a good point. There were a few powers like Bolt I just assumed I couldn't do, I will have to ask my GM what he's willing to allow.